# Why are my 5th and 6th screens not showing?

Tags: pysimplegui

I am quite confused as to why after my 4th screen, the 5th and 6th screens do not show and the program crashes. What am I doing wrong? I have tried debugging the code but I simply do not understand how to fix this issue. The 5th and 6th screens will not show and it will crash after the 4th screen.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
import csv
sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('Reddit')

binFile1 = binFile2  = binFile3 = binFile4 = binFile5 = binFile6 = binFile7 = binFile8 = None
binFile9 = binFile10 = binFile11 = binFile12 = binFile13 = binFile14 = binFile15 = binFile16 = None

logFile = open("debug.txt", "w")

layout = [[sg.Text('How many driver bits do you need? (Enter a number between 1 and 71)')],
          [sg.Input(key='-IN-', enable_events=True)],
          [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT-')],
          [sg.Button('Next >'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

layout2 = [[sg.Text('How many bytes are needed? (Enter a number between 1 and 15)')],
           [sg.Input(key='num_bytes', enable_events = True)],
           [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT2-')],
           [sg.Button('< Prev'), sg.Button('Next >')]]

window1 = sg.Window('CSV to Binary', layout, element_justification='c')

window4_active = window5_active = window6_active = window3_active = window2_active = window4_active = False

while True:
    if not window2_active:
        event1, values1 = window1.read()
        if event1 is None or event1 == 'Exit':
            break

        if event1 == '-IN-' and values1['-IN-'] and values1['-IN-'][-1] not in ('0123456789.'):
            window1['-IN-'].update(values1['-IN-'][:-1])
        if len(values1['-IN-']) > 2:
            window1.Element('-IN-').Update(values1['-IN-'][:-1])

    if not window2_active and event1 == 'Next >':
        window2_active = True
        window1.hide()
        layout2 = [[sg.Text('How many bytes are needed? (Enter a number between 1 and 15)')],
                   [sg.Input(key = 'num_bytes', enable_events = True)],
                   [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT2-')],
                   [sg.Button('< Prev'), sg.Button('Next >')]]
        window2 = sg.Window('CSV to Binary', layout2, element_justification='c')
        event2, values2 = window2.read()

    def open_output_files(num_bytes):
        global binFile1, binFile2, binFile3, binFile4, binFile5, binFile6, binFile7, binFile8, \
           binFile9, binFile10, binFile11, binFile12, binFile13, binFile14, binFile15, binFile16
        if 'num_bytes' == "1":
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
        elif 'num_bytes' == "2":
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
                binFile2 = open("158.bin", "wb")
        elif 'num_bytes' =="3":
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
                binFile2 = open("158.bin", "wb")
                binFile3 = open("159.bin", "wb")
        elif 'num_bytes' == "4":
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
                binFile2 = open("158.bin", "wb")
                binFile3 = open("159.bin", "wb")
                binFile4 = open("160.bin", "wb")
        elif 'num_bytes' == "5":
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
                binFile2 = open("158.bin", "wb")
                binFile3 = open("159.bin", "wb")
                binFile4 = open("160.bin", "wb")
                binFile5 = open("161.bin", "wb")
        elif 'num_bytes' == "6":
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
                binFile2 = open("158.bin", "wb")
                binFile3 = open("159.bin", "wb")
                binFile4 = open("160.bin", "wb")
                binFile5 = open("161.bin", "wb")
                binFile5 = open("162.bin", "wb")
        elif 'num_bytes' == "6":
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
                binFile2 = open("158.bin", "wb")
                binFile3 = open("159.bin", "wb")
                binFile4 = open("160.bin", "wb")
                binFile5 = open("161.bin", "wb")
                binFile5 = open("162.bin", "wb")
        elif 'num_bytes' == "7":
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
                binFile2 = open("158.bin", "wb")
                binFile3 = open("159.bin", "wb")
                binFile4 = open("160.bin", "wb")
                binFile5 = open("161.bin", "wb")
                binFile6 = open("162.bin", "wb")
                binFile7 = open("163.bin", "wb")
        elif 'num_bytes' == "8":
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
                binFile2 = open("158.bin", "wb")
                binFile3 = open("159.bin", "wb")
                binFile4 = open("160.bin", "wb")
                binFile5 = open("161.bin", "wb")
                binFile6 = open("162.bin", "wb")
                binFile7 = open("163.bin", "wb")
                binFile8 = open("164.bin", "wb")
        elif 'num_bytes' == '9':
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
                binFile2 = open("158.bin", "wb")
                binFile3 = open("159.bin", "wb")
                binFile4 = open("160.bin", "wb")
                binFile5 = open("161.bin", "wb")
                binFile6 = open("162.bin", "wb")
                binFile7 = open("163.bin", "wb")
                binFile8 = open("164.bin", "wb")
                binFile9 = open("165.bin", "wb")
        elif 'num_bytes' == '10':
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
                binFile2 = open("158.bin", "wb")
                binFile3 = open("159.bin", "wb")
                binFile4 = open("160.bin", "wb")
                binFile5 = open("161.bin", "wb")
                binFile6 = open("162.bin", "wb")
                binFile7 = open("163.bin", "wb")
                binFile8 = open("164.bin", "wb")
                binFile9 = open("165.bin", "wb")
                binFile10 = open("166.bin", "wb")
        elif 'num_bytes' == '11':
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
                binFile2 = open("158.bin", "wb")
                binFile3 = open("159.bin", "wb")
                binFile4 = open("160.bin", "wb")
                binFile5 = open("161.bin", "wb")
                binFile6 = open("162.bin", "wb")
                binFile7 = open("163.bin", "wb")
                binFile8 = open("164.bin", "wb")
                binFile9 = open("165.bin", "wb")
                binFile10 = open("166.bin", "wb")
                binFile11 = open("167.bin", "wb")
        elif 'num_bytes' == '12':
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
                binFile2 = open("158.bin", "wb")
                binFile3 = open("159.bin", "wb")
                binFile4 = open("160.bin", "wb")
                binFile5 = open("161.bin", "wb")
                binFile6 = open("162.bin", "wb")
                binFile7 = open("163.bin", "wb")
                binFile8 = open("164.bin", "wb")
                binFile9 = open("165.bin", "wb")
                binFile10 = open("166.bin", "wb")
                binFile11 = open("167.bin", "wb")
                binFile12 = open("168.bin", "wb")
        elif 'num_bytes' == '13':
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
                binFile2 = open("158.bin", "wb")
                binFile3 = open("159.bin", "wb")
                binFile4 = open("160.bin", "wb")
                binFile5 = open("161.bin", "wb")
                binFile6 = open("162.bin", "wb")
                binFile7 = open("163.bin", "wb")
                binFile8 = open("164.bin", "wb")
                binFile9 = open("165.bin", "wb")
                binFile10 = open("166.bin", "wb")
                binFile11 = open("167.bin", "wb")
                binFile12 = open("168.bin", "wb")
                binFile13 = open("169.bin", "wb")
        elif 'num_bytes' == '14':
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
                binFile2 = open("158.bin", "wb")
                binFile3 = open("159.bin", "wb")
                binFile4 = open("160.bin", "wb")
                binFile5 = open("161.bin", "wb")
                binFile6 = open("162.bin", "wb")
                binFile7 = open("163.bin", "wb")
                binFile8 = open("164.bin", "wb")
                binFile9 = open("165.bin", "wb")
                binFile10 = open("166.bin", "wb")
                binFile11 = open("167.bin", "wb")
                binFile12 = open("168.bin", "wb")
                binFile13 = open("169.bin", "wb")
                binFile14 = open("170.bin", "wb")
        elif 'num_bytes' == '15':
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
                binFile2 = open("158.bin", "wb")
                binFile3 = open("159.bin", "wb")
                binFile4 = open("160.bin", "wb")
                binFile5 = open("161.bin", "wb")
                binFile6 = open("162.bin", "wb")
                binFile7 = open("163.bin", "wb")
                binFile8 = open("164.bin", "wb")
                binFile9 = open("165.bin", "wb")
                binFile10 = open("166.bin", "wb")
                binFile11 = open("167.bin", "wb")
                binFile12 = open("168.bin", "wb")
                binFile13 = open("169.bin", "wb")
                binFile14 = open("170.bin", "wb")
                binFile15 = open("171.bin", "wb")
        else:
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
                binFile2 = open("158.bin", "wb")
                binFile3 = open("159.bin", "wb")
                binFile4 = open("160.bin", "wb")
                binFile5 = open("161.bin", "wb")
                binFile6 = open("162.bin", "wb")
                binFile7 = open("163.bin", "wb")
                binFile8 = open("164.bin", "wb")
                binFile9 = open("165.bin", "wb")
                binFile10 = open("166.bin", "wb")
                binFile11 = open("167.bin", "wb")
                binFile12 = open("168.bin", "wb")
                binFile13 = open("169.bin", "wb")
                binFile14 = open("170.bin", "wb")
                binFile15 = open("171.bin", "wb")
                binFile16 = open("172.bin", "wb")

    if window2_active:
        event2 = window2.read()[0]
        event2, values2 = window2.read()
        if event2 in (None, 'Exit', '< Prev'):
            window2_active = False
            window2.close()
            window1.un_hide()
        elif event2 == 'Next >':
            window3_active = True
            window2_active = False
            window2.hide()
            layout3 = [[sg.Text('Choose .CSV/Excel File')],
                      [[sg.In() ,sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Excel Files ONLY (.xlsx)", "*.xlsx"),))]],
                       [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT3-')],
                       [sg.Button('< Prev'), sg.Button('Next >')]]
            window3 = sg.Window('CSV to Binary', layout3, element_justification='c')

    if window3_active:
        event3 = window3.read()[0]
        event3, values3 = window3.read()
        if event3 in (None, 'Exit', '< Prev'):
            window3.close()
            window3_active = False
            window2_active = True
            window2.un_hide()
        elif event3 == 'Next >':
            window4_active = True
            window3_active = False
            window3.hide()
            layout4 = [[sg.Text('Please choose where you would like to export the .BIN files...')],
                       [[sg.In(), sg.FolderBrowse()]],
                       [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT4-')],
                       [sg.Button('< Prev'), sg.Button('Next >')]]
            window4 = sg.Window('CSV to Binary', layout4, element_justification='c')

    linecnt = 0

    if window4_active:
        event4 = window4.read()[0]
        event4, values4 = window4.read()
        if event4 in (None, 'Exit', '< Prev'):
            window4.close()
            window4_active = False
            window3_active = True
            window3.un_hide()
        elif event4 == 'Next >':
            window5_active = True
            window4_active = False
            window4.hide()
            layout5 = [[sg.Text('Please go back and verify your settings. \nIf everything looks correct, click Next >.')],
                       [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT5-')],
                       [sg.Button('< Prev'), sg.Button('Next >')]]
            window6 = sg.Window('CSV to Binary', layout5, element_justification='c')

            start_time = time.time()
            init = True
            linecnt = 0
            open_output_files(9) # MODIFY THIS TO BE # OF BURN IN CHANNELS / 8 (Round up!!!)

            with open('layout3', "rb") as vecfile:
                vectors = csv.reader(vecfile, delimiter = ',')
                for vec in vectors:
                    if(linecnt < 0):
                        next
                else:
                        temp_vec = ''
                        #vec = int('0')

                        for i in range(0, 72):
                            vec = str((temp_vec) + str(i))

                        print(str(temp_vec))

                        temp_vec = str(temp_vec.translate({ord(x): '0' for x in ['Z', 'X', 'H', 'L']}))

                        #if int(temp_vec) % 8 != 0:
                        vec_str = temp_vec + ''  #ADD PADDED 0'S TO MAKE OVERALL NUMBER OF VECTORS % 8 = 0

                print(vec_str)
                vec_str = vec_str[::-1]
                print(vec_str)
                print(linecnt, vec_str[:8])# for debug

                if 'num_bytes' == "1":
                            byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2) # COMMENT OR UNCOMMENT # OF BYTES REQUIRED FOR BURNIN SETUP
                            binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')) # COMMENT OR UNCOMMENT # OF BYTES REQUIRED FOR BURNIN SETUP
                            binFile1.close()

                elif 'num_bytes' == "2":
                            byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)
                            binFile2.write(byte2.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')) #Work on having gui select which one to use and what to comment out
                            binFile2.close()

                elif 'num_bytes' == "3":
                            byte3 = int(vec_str[23:15:-1],2)
                            binFile3.write(byte3.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                            binFile3.close()

                elif 'num_bytes' == "4":
                            byte4 = int(vec_str[31:23:-1],2)
                            binFile4.write(byte4.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                            binFile4.close()

                elif 'num_bytes' == "5":
                            byte5 = int(vec_str[39:31:-1],2)
                            binFile5.write(byte5.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                            binFile5.close()

                elif 'num_bytes' == "6":
                            byte6 = int(vec_str[47:39:-1],2)
                            binFile6.write(byte6.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                            binFile6.close()

                elif 'num_bytes' == "7":
                            byte7 = int(vec_str[55:47:-1],2)
                            binFile7.write(byte7.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                            binFile7.close()

                elif 'num_bytes' == "8":
                            byte8 = int(vec_str[63:55:-1],2)
                            binFile8.write(byte8.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                            binFile8.close()

                elif 'num_bytes' == "9":
                            byte9 = int(vec_str[71:63:-1],2)
                            binFile9.write(byte9.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                            binFile9.close()

                elif 'num_bytes' == "10":
                            byte10 = int(vec_str[79:71:-1],2)
                            binFile10.write(byte10.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                            binFile10.close()

                elif 'num_bytes' == "11":
                            byte11 = int(vec_str[87:79:-1],2)
                            binFile11.write(byte11.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                            binFile11.close()

                elif 'num_bytes' == "12":
                            byte12 = int(vec_str[95:87:-1],2)
                            binFile12.write(byte12.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                            binFile12.close()

                elif 'num_bytes' == "13":
                            byte13 = int(vec_str[103:95:-1],2)
                            binFile13.write(byte13.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                            binFile13.close()

                elif 'num_bytes' == "14":
                            byte14 = int(vec_str[111:103:-1],2)
                            binFile14.write(byte14.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                            binFile14.close()

                elif 'num_bytes' == "15":
                            byte15 = int(vec_str[119:111:-1],2)
                            binFile15.write(byte15.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                            binFile15.close()

                elif 'num_bytes' == "16":
                            byte16 = int(vec_str[127:119:-1],2)
                            binFile16.write(byte16.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
                            binFile16.close()

    linecnt += 1

if window6_active:
    event6 = window6.read()[0]
    layout7 = [[sg.Text('Compilation Complete! \nYour files have been saved in your chosen directory.')],
             [sg.Button('Finish!')]]
    window7 = sg.Window('CSV to Binary', layout7, element_justification='c')


window1.close()
```

Comment: What's the crash info say?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't check the code for your issue for it looks like that the code is long and much complex.

Maybe you can put the layout of each window into a Column element and set only which Column visible.

Another way is to put all elements into only one window at the same time for there're not too many elements in all of your windows, and it is not required to have them time dependent.

You can use a popup window to replace your last window for that is what it for.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkBlue')

layouts = [
    [   # Layout 0
        [sg.Text('How many driver bits do you need? (Enter a number between 1 and 71)')],
        [sg.Input(key='-IN0-', expand_x=True, enable_events=True)],
        [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT0-')],
        [sg.Button('< Prev', disabled=True, key='Prev 0'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('Next >', key='Next 0')]],
    [   # Layout 1
        [sg.Text('How many bytes are needed? (Enter a number between 1 and 15)')],
        [sg.Input(key='-IN1-', expand_x=True, enable_events = True)],
        [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT1-')],
        [sg.Button('< Prev', key='Prev 1'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('Next >', key='Next 1')]],
    [   # Layout 2
        [sg.Text('Choose .CSV/Excel File')],
        [sg.Input(key='-IN2-', expand_x=True), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Excel Files ONLY (.xlsx)", "*.xlsx"),))],
        [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT2-')],
        [sg.Button('< Prev', key='Prev 2'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('Next >', key='Next 2')]],
    [   # Layout 3
        [sg.Text('Please choose where you would like to export the .BIN files...')],
        [sg.Input(key='-IN3-', expand_x=True), sg.FolderBrowse()],
        [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT3-')],
        [sg.Button('< Prev', key='Prev 3'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('Next >', key='Next 3')]],
    [   # Layout 4
        [sg.Text('Please go back and verify your settings. \nIf everything looks correct, click Next >.')],
        [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT4-')],
        [sg.Button('< Prev', key='Prev 4'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('Next >', key='Next 4')]],
    [   # Layout 5
        [sg.Text('Compilation Complete! \nYour files have been saved in your chosen directory.')],
        [sg.Text('Finish !', expand_x=True, justification='center')],
        [sg.Button('< Top', key='Top'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('Exit')]],
]

layout = [[sg.Column(item, visible=(i==0), key=f'Column {i}') for i, item in enumerate(layouts)]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, enable_close_attempted_event=True)
column = 0

def show(step):
    global column
    window[f'Column {column}'].update(visible=False)
    column += step
    window[f'Column {column}'].update(visible=True)
    window.refresh()
    window.move_to_center()

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    print(repr(event))
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT:
        if column in (0, 5):
            break
        else:
            show(-1)
    elif event in ('Exit', 'Finish!'):
        break
    elif event.startswith("Prev"):
        show(-1)
    elif event.startswith("Next"):
        show(+1)
    elif event == 'Top':
        show(-5)

window.close()
```

Note 1: You can use list to store all variables, like `binFile1`, `binFile2`, ... , `binFile16`, then you function `open_output_files` can be reduced to only 8 lines, not 162 lines.

```py
def open_output_files(num_bytes):
    try:
        count = int(num_bytes)
    except ValueError:
        count = 16
    if not (0 <= count <= 15):
        count = 16
    return [open(f"{157+i}.bin", "wb") for i in range(count)]
```

Note 2: Some condition checks in your code will always get the `False` result, like

```py
        if 'num_bytes' == "1":      # <=== Here
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
        elif 'num_bytes' == "2":    # <=== Here
                binFile1 = open("157.bin", "wb")
                binFile2 = open("158.bin", "wb")
```

```py
                if 'num_bytes' == "1":      # <=== Here
                            byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2) # COMMENT OR UNCOMMENT # OF BYTES REQUIRED FOR BURNIN SETUP
                            binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')) # COMMENT OR UNCOMMENT # OF BYTES REQUIRED FOR BURNIN SETUP
                            binFile1.close()

                elif 'num_bytes' == "2":    # <=== Here
                            byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)
                            binFile2.write(byte2.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')) #Work on having gui select which one to use and what to comment out
                            binFile2.close()
```